# Where is this message printed out?

Tags: shell, alpine-linux

I am working in Alpine Linux and I cannot wrap my head around the following behavior of the `sh` shell:

```
/ # vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf > /dev/null
500 OOPS: bad bool value in config file for: hide_ids
/ # vsftpd /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf 2> /dev/null
500 OOPS: bad bool value in config file for: hide_ids
```

Where is the message printed out? Was it `stdout` or `stderr`?

Comment: You redirected `stdout` to `/dev/null`. So can it be `stdout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vsftpd` sources define a constant, `VSFTP_COMMAND_FD`, as the number zero.  This happens to be the file descriptor that errors are written to.

```
$ grep -F VSFTP_COMMAND_FD defs.h
#define VSFTP_COMMAND_FD        0
```

However strange it may seem, the code is writing error messages to the standard *input* stream.

```c
void
bug(const char* p_text)
{
  /* Rats. Try and write the reason to the network for diagnostics */
  vsf_sysutil_activate_noblock(VSFTP_COMMAND_FD);
  (void) vsf_sysutil_write_loop(VSFTP_COMMAND_FD, "500 OOPS: ", 10);
  (void) vsf_sysutil_write_loop(VSFTP_COMMAND_FD, p_text,
                                vsf_sysutil_strlen(p_text));
  (void) vsf_sysutil_write_loop(VSFTP_COMMAND_FD, "\r\n", 2);
  vsf_sysutil_exit(2);
}
```

Testing:

```
$ ./vsftpd >/dev/null
500 OOPS: vsftpd: must be started as root (see run_as_launching_user option)
$ ./vsftpd 2>/dev/null
500 OOPS: vsftpd: must be started as root (see run_as_launching_user option)
$ ./vsftpd </dev/null
$
```

So, redirecting `/dev/null` into the application silences the errors. You could also use `0>/dev/null` to show your intent to discard any output sent by the application to that particular file descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

`vsftpd` is typically invoked by `inetd` with its fd 0 (stdin) being the TCP command socket from the client.

So that's where it writes that status message.

You could do:

```
vsftpd configfile < /dev/null
```

to make it go away, not that it would do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

First, that message does not come from the shell. `hide_ids` is a configuration option for vsftpd, not of the shell, so there's no reason to assume to assume the shell would print anything that refers to it. (Yes, there is a distinction, and yes, it's important.)

Second, you've shown vsftpd launched with both stdout and stderr redirected to `/dev/null` and it's still visible, so we must assume the message is printed to *neither*.

Some utilities explicitly open a new handle to the current terminal via `/dev/tty`, often to do something that requires user interaction without messing up with possible redirections. This is how e.g. the SSH client can ask for your password even with both stdout and stderr redirected away.

However, that's not the case here either. As [Kusalananda's answer says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/627076/170373), vsftpd prints fatal errors like that to a command fd, named `VSFTP_COMMAND_FD` in the source. Presumably it uses the same fd to read commands, too, and it's defined to be fd 0, or *stdin*. This does actually work, since all of stdin, stdout and stderr are usually opened read-write. On Linux, you can check this by looking at the permissions of the entries in `/proc/<pid>/fd` for a process launched normally. Easiest to do it with `ls`:

```
$ ls -l /proc/self/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 64 Jan  1 13:54 0 -> /dev/pts/18
lrwx------ 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 64 Jan  1 13:54 1 -> /dev/pts/18
lrwx------ 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 64 Jan  1 13:54 2 -> /dev/pts/18
lr-x------ 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 64 Jan  1 13:54 3 -> /proc/8955/fd/
```

All of 0, 1 and 2 are marked `rwx`, so they're open in read-write mode. (I'm not sure what the `x` bit implies here, if anything.)

Answer (score -1):

You redirected `stdout` to `/dev/null`. So it can not be `stdout`. This leaves `stderr`.

Redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`, to test this hypothesis.